# Django 1.11 get_template with full path of template

Tags: django, django-1.11

I have the following search order of directories in `settings.py`

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'templates'),
         os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src', 'py', 'my_project', 'app1', 'templates'),
         os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src', 'py', 'my_project', 'app2', 'templates')),
],
```

There is a template `test_template.html` under app1 and app2.
I want to programatically load `app1/test_template1.html` **or** `app2\test_template2.html` by giving `django.template.loader.get_template()` the **full path** to the file (so that the correct template be loaded). But despite giving the full path it still loads the `app/test_template1.html` because it has higher priority in search order. Reversing the order will not help because then it will start loading `app2/test_template.html`.
I can keep the filenames unique but it should be something simpler.
Any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: How are You loading these templates? Through your views.py file?

Comment: Nope. I have a script that runs inside shell and also on website front end through django commands. It has full file path refrences to templates and then tries to load them for some processing.